# Multiple Div's Does Not Stay In One Row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

I'm trying to use multiple divs inside a row that contains 2 different columns, so when I place the content inside those divs I cannot figure out how to display all to be stuck together rather then one dropped over another.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TheGBCoder/emn2ryf6/

Please reffer to this picture for more details:

[image]

```
<div id="main" class="main">
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 no1">

            <p><img src="img/sample1.png"/></p>

        </div>    

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-8 no2">

            <!--Tab 2-->
            <div class="customno2">
            <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
            <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
            </br>
            <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

            <div class="btn-group customgbtn" role="group">
            <button id="custombtn1" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal"></span>
            </button>
            <button id="custombtn2" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            READ THE FULL WELCOME</button>

            </div>

        </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 no3">
<ul id="social">
                <li><img src="img/facebook.png"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li><img src="img/twitter.png"><a href="#"></a></li>

            </ul>
    </div>

            <div class="col-md-12"> </div>
    <!--
    <div class="col-md-1 no3">
            <ul id="social">
                <li><img src="img/facebook.png"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li><img src="img/twitter.png"><a href="#"></a></li>

            </ul>
    </div>-->

</div>
</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do the job:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-8"> </div>
        <div class="col-md-4> </div>
        <div class="col-md-12"> </div>
    </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: Please have a look https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5za-Wfvmxv2NURDallRT3BCUXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: also did add the ( <div class="col-md-12"> </div> ) but still displaying as it was , the content inside the divs doesnt not shirink !!

Comment: Have you checked that there is no element inside the divs that does not fit and is pushing the content downwards?

Comment: Yes i did , there is no css elements inside those div but I have used div ids and did custom styles

Comment: It has to be one of your custom styles or images. I just run the code you posted and I get the expected result :-)